# PLotly Scatter: Moving the colorbar to the left not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

Here's the piece of code I am using (This plots a scatter plot with a colorbar to the right of the plot)

```
import plotly.express as px

data_y = [758, 742.19, 731.57, 728.36, 718.76, 707.56]
data_x = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]

data_x_labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

fig = px.scatter(x=data_x, y=data_y, trendline="ols",
                  trendline_color_override="black",)

fig.update_traces(marker=dict( size=10, color=data_y,
                              colorscale='YlGn', showscale=True, 
                              reversescale=False, opacity=1),
                 )

fig.update_coloraxes(colorscale="YlGn")

fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=data_x, ticktext=data_x_labels)
fig.update_layout(width=650, height=600, margin=dict(l=50, r=50, b=50, t=50))

fig.show()
```

What I have done is added this:

```
fig.update_coloraxes(colorbar_xanchor='left')
```

to move the colorbar to the left. But it does not work and the colorbar stays at the right. What would be the correct way to move the colorbar to the right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `colorbar_x` to a negative value:

```
import plotly.express as px

data_y = [758, 742.19, 731.57, 728.36, 718.76, 707.56]
data_x = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]

data_x_labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

fig = px.scatter(x=data_x, y=data_y, trendline="ols",
                  trendline_color_override="black",)

fig.update_traces(marker=dict( size=10, color=data_y, 
                              colorscale='YlGn', showscale=True,
                              colorbar_x=-0.3),
                 )


fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=data_x, ticktext=data_x_labels)
fig.update_layout(width=650, height=600, margin=dict(l=50, r=50, b=50, t=50))

fig.show()
```

[image]